# Как отправить на почту данные вместе с картинкой?

Tags: javascript, php, email, sendmail

Как с помощью js (если нельзя, то какие методы есть) отправить данные (а именно, объект) на почту? Есть кнопка, при которой формируется объект, и его нужно кинуть на почту.

Вот тут пытаюсь отправит объект:

```
$.ajax({
  url: 'main.php',
  type: 'POST',
  contentType: 'application/json',
  data: JSON.stringify(total),
  success: function(msg) {
    console.log(msg);
    if (msg == 'ok') {
      alert('Сообщение отправлено');

    } else {
      alert('Ошибка');
    }
  }
});
```

Вот пхп, пытаюсь записать в переменную%

```
$total = $_POST['total'];
$total = json_decode( $total );
```

Answer (score 0):

Вот пример из моего рабочего кода:

Html:

```
<form action="/index.php/user/upload_id_verify/" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="id_verify" id="id_verify">
    <button type="submit" class="writer_button" style="display: none; width: 100px;" id="id_button">Upload file</button>
</form>
```

JS:

```
function submit_id_verify() {
    var form = $('#id_verify').attr('files')[0];
    var formData = new FormData(form);

    $.ajax({
        url: '/index.php/user/upload_id_verify/',  
        cache: false,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        data: formData,    
        contentType: 'multipart/form-data',                     
        type: 'POST',
        success: function(data){
            console.log(data);
        }
    });
}
```

Php:

```
....
if ($_FILES['id_verify']['size'] > 1600000) {
          echo "must be up to 1500kb in size"; exit();
 }
if (!empty($_FILES['id_verify']['tmp_name'])) {
    $upload = new stdClass();
    $upload->file = $this->clean_input($_FILES['id_verify']['tmp_name'], 1);
    $upload->name = $this->clean_input($_FILES['id_verify']['name'], 1);
....
```

Comment: Через php  почти работает, не подскажешь, как отправить объект через ajax?    Код добавил в вопрос)

Comment: если это файл с данными (фото, музыка, приложение и что-то иное отличное от текста), то перед отправкой таких данных их нужно кодировать через например https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.base64-encode.php, или лучше использовать что-то типа https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer - здесь есть примеры как можно просто и удобно аттачить файлы

Comment: Использую phpmailer,  но не в этом сейчас проблема. Мне нужно свойства объекта присвоить в пхп переменные. А у меня не получается(

Comment: пример кода, где вы получаете объект, и где его нужно отдать, можно?

возможно, что такой вариант поможет:

$file_tmp  = $_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];
$file_name = $_FILES['image']['name'];
$mail->AddAttachment($file_tmp, $file_name); 

где $mail - объект вашего phpmailer

Comment: Пример кода выше, в вопросе. Объект я создаю в js файле. Мне этот объект нужно распихать в пхп переменные

Comment: я обновил примером из моего рабочего кода, форма получает данные и через ajax сохраняет файл и данные про него, надеюсь поможет